# Get element based on indexes of strings

Tags: javascript, jquery

So i have this string:

```
...
11007,"test,Biovegan,"50g",4005394284292,7.42,da
11008,"test4",Biovegan,"55g",40042,8.42,da
...
```

it represents data from some products, the 1st element is the code, the 2nd is the name, the 3rd is the vendor, the 4th is the weight, the 5th is the barcode, the 6th is the price, and the 7th is a random boolean.

I would like to get the price with a javascript string function but I can find a proper way to do so.

I would like to get the price knowing that I have the barcode, so If I want the price for the barcode: `4005394284292` it would return 7.42, if i provide the barcode :`40042` it would return 8.42

Comment: And what have you tried so far and in what way did you fail? This should be fairly easy with the usage of [split()](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split)

Comment: So I tried finding the index of the barcode, and finding the first comma after that index, but couldn't wrap my head around how to do it properly. I just found out the solution, transformed my string list into an array, found the index of the barcode in that array and just added a array[index + 1] to find the price

Comment: Sounds reasonable. Note that it is [encouraged to answer your own question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) if you can.

Comment: I can do so in 2 days.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most neat solution i can think of is to create an object with this format :

```
{
   "4005394284292": "7.42",
   "40042": "8.42"
   ....
}
```

so you can get the price with only : dbMap[barcode]

```js
const data = `11007,"test,Biovegan,"50g",4005394284292,7.42,da
11008,"test4",Biovegan,"55g",40042,8.42,da`

let lines = data.split('\n')
let arr = lines.map(line => line.split(','))
let dbMap = arr.reduce((db, e) => {
  db[e[4]] = e[5];
  return db;
}, {})

console.log(dbMap)
```

Comment: corrected  db[e[4]] = e[5] and not db[e[4]] = db[e[5]]

Answer (score 1):

```
  var bodyArray = bodyHTML.split(',')

  var codIndex = bodyArray.indexOf(barcode)

  var price = bodyArray[codIndex + 1]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of the `split()` function in JavaScript to seperate your string using the comma as a delimiter. The function `getProductPrice()` below should do as you asked, you just pass the barcode of product you want the price for, and it will return it as a result. The `products` array contains a list of all your products.

```js
let products = [
        '11007,"test,Biovegan,"50g",4005394284292,7.42,da',
        '11008,"test4",Biovegan,"55g",40042,8.42,da',
    ];

    let barcodeToFind = '4005394284292';

    function getProductPrice(barcode) {
        let foundProduct = false;
        for (var i = 0; i < products.length; i++) {
            let productData = products[i].split(","); // Split the data by the comma as a delimiter.

            if(productData[4] === barcode) {
                foundProduct = productData[5];
            }
        }

        return foundProduct;
    }

    console.log(getProductPrice(barcodeToFind));
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script> <!-- JQuery -->
```

Comment: the big string is in this format: `11007,"test,Biovegan,"50g",4005394284292,7.42,da
11008,"test4",Biovegan,"55g",40042,8.42,da` , i found a solution, but thank you anyway

Answer (score 0):

```
const str = "11007,test,Biovegan,50g,4005394284292,7.42,da".split(",").splice(4, 2);
const str2 = "11008,test4,Biovegan,55g,40042,8.42,da".split(",").splice(4, 2);

const codes = [
    str, 
    str2    
]

function getPrice(barcode) {
    for(let i = 0; i < codes.length; ++i) {
        if(codes[i][0] == barcode) {
            return codes[i][1];
        }
    }
    return false;
}

getPrice(40042);
```

Comment: I don't have the strings as 2 separate entities, my string is a big list of products with commas.